# Webpage routing according to user type in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have used `make:auth` command to create basic register and login. I have created an extra field in register page which gets user type*(admin,employee or visitor)*.

Now my problem is I need to navigate to three different page for each of them by accessing that user type from the users table in database. Any help any suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? please clarify.

Comment: in my register page i got email,password and usertype . then i stored it in users table.when i login it goes to home page.but my problem is i need to navigate to three diff different pages depending upon the user type data which is stored on users table.(for example ,if admin login then it must go a particular webpage similarly for others )

Comment: so you need that for example, an admin when he logs in, to go into the admin page, and visitors to visitors page etc?

Comment: yes... yes i expect suggestions

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Laravel 5 comes with `\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware class which intended to do redirection once user logged in.

So in this case, the handle function of the middleware would be

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        $userType = Auth::user()->type;

        if ($userType == 'admin') {
           return redirect('/admin');
        } else if ($userType == 'employee') {
            return redirect('/employee');
        } else if ($userType == 'visitor') {
            return redirect('/visitor');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Laravel too, has leave out a blank `authenticated` method which you can fill out on `\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` which is inherited from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
        $userType = $user->type;

        if ($userType == 'admin') {
           return redirect('/admin');
        } else if ($userType == 'employee') {
            return redirect('/employee');
        } else if ($userType == 'visitor') {
            return redirect('/visitor');
        }
}
```